# Allow a module loaded with imp to access local variables in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a dynamic module-loading system in python using the `imp` module. I have two files, `x.py` and `y.py`, and I want to load `y.py` from `x.py` and have `y.py` be able to access variables declared in `x.py`. Is this at all possible?

From a code point, this is what I have:

**x.py**

```py
import imp

global_var = 7
imp.load_source( 'y', 'y.py' )
print( global_var )
```

**y.py**

```py
global_var = 3
```

But I can't update `x.py`'s `global_var` from `y.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module `x` and `y` have separated namespace. Changing module-level variable in `y` does not affect the namespace of `x` module.

How about following approach?

```
import imp

global_var = 7
y = imp.load_source('y', 'y.py') # <---
global_var = y.global_var        # <---
print(global_var)
```

**UPDATE** response to the comment.

You can use [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) or [`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) (Python 2.x only). **not recommended**:

```
global_var = 7
#execfile('y.py')   # Python 2.x
with open('y.py') as f:
    exec(f.read())
print(global_var)
```

Comment: I also want to be able to access functions in `x` from `y` though.

Comment: @RCHowe, How about define functions needed to be used in a separated module, and import that from `y` ?

Comment: Yes, but I want the functions to be able to access other things in `x` as well; if I separated them out into another module `z` there would be the same problem getting things from `x` into `z`.

Comment: @RCHowe, You can use something like [`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile). But I don't recommend it.

Comment: @RCHowe, I updated the answer with the code that use `exec`/`execfile`. Check it out.